# Fixed Background and div starting beneath the page

Tags: html, css

I want to create a simple css styling yet seems so hard to implement

what i want to achieve is to have a background image the is fixed to fit the whole page, and i want the content of the website to be "underneath" the image, which means when the user visit the page he will see only the background, after scrolling down the content will appear from underneath

i tried this

```css
.content {
  background-image: url('../img/header-bg.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.content-title {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fed136;
}

.page-body::before {
  position: relative;
}

.page-body {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.view-more {
  width: 100%;
  height: 125px;
  border: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="content-title">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="page-body">
  <button class="view-more">View More</button>
  <div class="page-holder">
    <button>Click Me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

the problem here is that the html tags i add beneath the "view-more" button pushes the "view-more" button upwards instead of staying beneath it

how can i achieve such result ?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand your question. If the image is fixed in place on top of your content... how will the user be able to see any of the content underneath when they scroll down? The image would still be on top of the content if both the image and the content never moved. Are you looking for a **parallax** effect? Or perhaps some transparency?

Comment: position fixed will make the content float over it unless you forced push the content down

Comment: I am not sure what are you trying to ask in the question, but have you tried `position:sticky`?

Answer (score 0):

For `page-body`, use `top: 100%` & `position:absolute`. Also, remove the before css

```css
.content {
  background-image: url('../img/header-bg.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.content-title {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fed136;
}

.page-body {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 100%;
}

.view-more {
  width: 100%;
  height: 125px;
  border: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="content-title">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="page-body">
  <button class="view-more">View More</button>
  <div class="page-holder">
    <button>Click Me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed your CSS a bit because I needed to start from scratch, but I think this is what you wanted to accomplish. I used z-index to specify what elements go on top. I also added .page-body { top:100%; } like @nikhil mentioned.

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="content-title">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="page-body">
  <button class="view-more">View More</button>
  <div class="page-holder">
    <button>Click Me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.content {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
}

.content-title {
  display: table;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: yellow;
}

h1 {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.page-body {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 100%;
}
```